# Booting Lubuntu I get EDIC Checksum is invalid remainder is 8 error

Tags: lubuntu

On-boot I get  `EDID checksum is invalid, remainder is 8 error`.  The error doesn't seem to cause any problems and Lubuntu continues to load and everything seems to be OK.

I had to add the Battery Indicator and I did set the `Laptop=yes` thing in the config file to get the power manager to auto load on start but would love to solve the E`DID error`. Can anyone please help.

On looking at the `lspci -v` output I can see that the VGA Compatible controller is 945GSE Express Integ and the Display controller is 945GM/GMS/GME, can anyone suggest anything, I am not an experienced Linux user but I have not found much on Google.

Comment: This might be of help: http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=15374 -- please post an answer here if you figure this out :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried many things but not the `nomodeset` and guess what? It works.  Anyone else having the same problem can follow the instructions here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132

Basically the instruction was adding `nomodeset` option to `/etc/default/grub` files `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` key. Like this

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

and it worked great.  The boot time is a little longer but no EDID errors.